# Calling a service method with serialised objects

Tags: c#, xml, wcf

I have a WCF service with a post method. This takes a single entity.

```
[OperationContract, FaultContract(typeof(ServiceError))]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped]
Entity SaveEntity(Entity entity);
```

I have a file with an xml serialised representation of these objects. I need to be able to post this xml to the service directly without deserialising it at the client side (architecture issues, we don't have the references).

Is it possible to do this by constructing a request with something like the HttpClient?

```
    var client = new HttpClient(HttpClient:);
    client.PostAsync("http://localhost:55217/MyService.svc/SaveEntity", new HttpContent
    {
      Headers = new System.Net.Http.Headers.HttpContentHeaders
      {
         // can I put my serialised xml here?
      }
    }
```

Here's the config:

```
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service behaviorConfiguration="Default" name="MyService">
        <endpoint address="" binding="webHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" behaviorConfiguration="webBehavior" bindingConfiguration="fullMessageSize" />
        <endpoint address="ws" binding="wsHttpBinding" contract="IMyService" bindingConfiguration="fullMessageSize" />
      </service>      
    </services>
    <behaviors>
      <endpointBehaviors>
        <behavior name="webBehavior">
          <webHttp />
        </behavior>
      </endpointBehaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
        <behavior name="Default">
          <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true" />
        </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
    </behaviors>
    <bindings>
      <webHttpBinding>
        <binding name="fullMessageSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" />
      </webHttpBinding>
      <wsHttpBinding>
        <binding name="fullMessageSize" maxReceivedMessageSize="104857600" />
      </wsHttpBinding>
    </bindings>
  </system.serviceModel>
```

Comment: Does your WCF service expose a RESTful endpoint?

Comment: @YuvalItzchakov expanded to include the endpoint configs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why not create an intermediate service?

```
[OperationContract, FaultContract(typeof(ServiceError))]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped]
Entity SaveEntity(XElement entitySerialized)
{
    var entity = Deserialize(entitySerialized);
    var realService = new MyServiceClient();
    return realService.SaveEntity(entity);
}
```

The intermediate service can have the references required for serialization.

You could consider creating a service-to-service endpoint for use between the intermediate service and the real service. That endpoint could use one of the faster bindings like `netTcpBinding`, that you might not want to use with your clients.